# Android shared view-model with live data with single time live data consumption

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, observers

I am using a shared view model and it is shared across two fragments. Both the fragments are listening for one live data and also handling it in the following way to consume it only once

```
fun getContentIfNotHandled(): StateData<T>? {
    return if (hasBeenHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        return this
    }
}
```

Now since I am observing one live data in two fragments, one of them is consuming the live data and the other one is getting a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your exact use case, but in my case, I had multiple fragments in a viewpager subscribing to a livedata Event. To ensure their are no conflicts, here is how I ensured that the fragment I wanted was consuming the correct event.

Using:

```
class ConditionalEventObserver<T>(
    private val shouldConsumeEvent: (T) -> Boolean,
    private val consumeEvent: (T) -> Unit
) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>) {
        if (!shouldConsumeEvent.invoke(event.peekContent())) return
        event.consumeContentIfAvailable()?.let { value ->
            consumeEvent(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Event class:

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {
    private var hasBeenHandled = false

    fun consumeContentIfAvailable(): T? =
        if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }

    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Assuming the event wraps an object like this for example

```
   data class EventPayload(
       val pageIndex: Int,
       //Other attributes
    )
```

Inside viewmodel:

```
val sharedEvent = MutableLiveData<Event<EventPayload>>()
```

In onViewCreated in each fragment:

```
viewModel.sharedEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, conditionallyConsumeEvent())

  private fun conditionallyConsumeEvent(): ConditionalEventObserver<ViewModel.SharedEvent> =
        ConditionalEventObserver({ eventPayload ->
            //Add your condition here, you can embed data in the Event Payload
            eventPayload.pageIndex == THIS_FRAGMENT_PAGE_INDEX // In my case, defined in my viewpager callback 
        }) { eventPayload ->
              handleEventInThisFragment(eventPayload)
        }
```

Not entirely sure if this is the best approach, but it is how I did it.

If on the other hand, you wish to simply read the value without consuming it from your fragments, then just peaking content (peekContent) on the event will work. But if you expect to consume the event more than once and trigger fragment callbacks from that, then you shouldn't be using an Event  & EventObserver.

Hope that helps!